# Heroku powered private restricted beta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku

I'd like to run an app in a restricted private beta on heroku.

We're changing the app regularly and haven't done a security audit.

To stop anyone exploiting stuff, we'd like to lock down the whole site, so you need a password to access anything.

Ideally similar to using .htaccess and .htpasswd files to lock an entire site on an Apache server.

Is there a simple one shot way to do this for a heroku hosted app?

Comment: Duplicate/similar of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839167/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-simple-http-authentication-for-an-app-on-heroku

Answer (score 5):

Just use `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic` in a before_filter in your ApplicationController.

See this Railscasts episode for instructions: http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication

Comment: tried it, but wouldn't play nice with devise. seemed to generate an infinite redirect loop

Comment: Ah! Just add `warden.custom_failure! if performed?` at the end of your filter method (as in https://gist.github.com/dc7906d07174c8514551)

Comment: I've tried this method with the `warden.custom_failure! if performed?`, and it works, but it causes another problem. When you try to login as a user (using devise), it says "wrong username and password", probably because it's trying to use the u/p I used for the HTTP Basic authentication. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` basically tells Apache to authenticate the user using a Basic Auth system. You can do the same with a pure-Rack layer.

See http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Auth/Basic.html

Because you are using Heroku, I assume you are deploying a Rack-compatible application (either a Rack, Rails or Sinatra app).

Answer (score 1):

on rack base like this :)

http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#auth

```
  use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Restricted Area" do |username, password|
    [username, password] == ['admin', 'admin']
  end
```