# Is there a way to set up simple http authentication for a Ruby on Rails app on heroku?

Tags: ruby, http, authentication, heroku

I want to set up a private staging server on heroku using simple http authentication. Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely. The simplest solution is to just put something in your application controller that uses Rails's built in basic auth support (see here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication) and just wrap it in a conditional for your `Rails.env`. Note that on Heroku, by default the RAILS_ENV is set to production, but you can change this for your non-production apps using `heroku config` (http://docs.heroku.com/config-vars).

You could also consider installing some roadblock-style Rack middleware, but I'd just go with the above.

Comment: It is better to store username and password as Heroku configuration variables (http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/4/7/config-vars/) and hashed (http://www.zacharyfox.com/blog/ruby-on-rails/password-hashing), although authentication should occur only if Rails.env == 'production' then.

Answer (score 53):

A cleaner way is to just drop in a couple lines of Rack middleware into your staging environment config, leaving controller logic alone:

```
# config/environments/staging.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.middleware.insert_after(::Rack::Lock, "::Rack::Auth::Basic", "Staging") do |u, p|
    [u, p] == ['username', 'password']
  end

  #... other config
end
```

This tip courtesy of Ole Morten Amundsen. More info plus Heroku password specification:

http://olemortenamundsen.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/ruby-secure-staging-environment-of-your-public-app-from-users-and-bots/

Comment: This solution is cleaner and makes more sense to me because is infrastucture agnostic.

Comment: Please note that index.html is served directly by the web server and not Rack-Rails and thus the index.html url won't be protected. Everything else served by Rails will be protected.

Answer (score 14):

On Rails4, I got "No such middleware to insert after: Rack::Lock" error. Replace Adam's code to the below:

```
# config/environments/staging.rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.middleware.use '::Rack::Auth::Basic' do |u, p|
    [u, p] == ['username', 'password']
  end
  # ...
end
```

See: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2013/6/4/tips-and-tricks-for-deploying-rails-4-apps-on-heroku

Comment: In Rails 5, middlewares wants the actual module, rather than a string. `config.middleware.use ::Rack::Auth::Basic`

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice heroku add-on that uses Mozilla Persona for authentication.  It's free for low-volume sites (under 10,000 authentications per month):

https://addons.heroku.com/wwwhisper

Very easy to install and configure.

Comment: Agreed. 2 users limit is the only possible issue.

Comment: US only. Also Mozilla Persona has been discontinued.  ```On November 30th, 2016, Mozilla will shut down the persona.org services. Persona.org and related domains will be taken offline.```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it using the application_controller.rb:

```
  # app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  before_filter :http_basic_auth

  def http_basic_auth
    if ENV['HTTP_AUTH'] =~ %r{(.+)\:(.+)}
      unless authenticate_with_http_basic { |user, password|  user == $1 && password == $2 }
        request_http_basic_authentication
      end
    end
  end
```

and then you need to export your values:
for development:

```
 export HTTP_AUTH=test:test
```

For heroku:

```
 heroku config:set HTTP_AUTH=test:test
```

Now when the window prompt you should enter for user/password => test/test.

That's it hope you find it useful.

Comment: Works great, thanks! My only suggestion is to add an `else` so that if the `HTTP_AUTH` variable isn't defined, it fails safely by blocking everyone: `else render file: "public/401.html", status: :unauthorized`

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for Rails 5+. In your `config/application.rb` or selected environment config:

```
config.middleware.use(Rack::Auth::Basic) do |u, p|
  [u, p] == [ENV['USER'], ENV['PASSWORD'] || SecureRandom.hex]
end
```

It's been pointed out in [Ole's blog post](https://olemortenamundsen.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/ruby-secure-staging-environment-of-your-public-app-from-users-and-bots/) to use ENV vars. I'd add that defaulting to a random password is a good idea in case the env var is not set.

To use it only on certain paths you can create your own middleware (refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34096415/2771889)):

```
class AdminAuth < Rack::Auth::Basic
  def call(env)
    req = Rack::Request.new(env)

    return @app.call(env) unless admin_path?(req)

    super
  end

  def admin_path?(req)
    req.path =~ /^\/admin\/*/
  end
end
```