# How can I keep my nodeJS Heroku app private? It should be accessible by authenticated user

Tags: node.js, authentication, heroku

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828616/how-can-i-keep-my-heroku-application-private) one, but my app is build on NodeJS.

I'm working on one POC.
I have a simple nodejs app on Heroku, it has one simple UI in HTML. Currently url of app is accessible by all the users. I want that URL should be accessible by only authenticated users, others can't access that URL.

My ultimate aim is to implement SSO for for authentication.

Comment: I think for SSO, you might need to create one authentication API or a gateway that allows only registered users to get the data.

Comment: This isn't really a Heroku question, it's a question about how you build your app. But did you see the comment on the issue you link to? "If anyone came here from Google looking for node.js, here's a [link](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-basic-authentication)"

Comment: that link is not working

Comment: @sfdc, so look at what it says: "nodejs and express basic authentication", and then search for that. There are plenty of tutorials out there that cover this.