# Rails: How to quickly secure entire site for development testing on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, heroku

I'm developing a site that will run from Heroku and I'm about to the point where I would like to push a prototype to Heroku for testing purposes and to make sure that I have all of the proper settings in place for it to run there. I would like a quick and dirty method of putting the entire site behind a simple login/password so that it's not open to the public during this period of light testing. It would be best if it is just a few lines of code and not deeply embedded in the app.

How would you go about quickly securing an entire Rails 3.2 app on Heroku?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`http_basic_authenticate_with` is a simple one liner if you add it to you application_controller.rb

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using Basic Auth, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839167/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-simple-http-authentication-for-an-app-on-heroku) covers your options pretty well.